# Android Camera 2 Api

Tags: android, android-camera

I have been trying camera2 API. I have downloaded code from

https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Video/index.html to learn about how it works. It works fine till I stop recording. When I stop recording it runs following code.

```
 private void stopRecordingVideo() {
        // UI
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        mBtn_Video.setText(R.string.record);
        // Stop recording
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            System.out.println("file " +  getVideoFile(activity));
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Video saved: " + getVideoFile(activity),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        startPreview();
```

at mMediaRecorder.stop(); it throw following error

```
01-12 16:24:23.115    2161-2200/com.cameratwoapi E/Surface﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
01-12 16:24:23.135    2161-2200/com.cameratwoapi E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 2200: swapBuffers(285): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
01-12 16:24:23.197    2161-2200/com.cameratwoapi E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0﹕ Received exception on GL render thread:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x3003
            at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:487)
            at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:480)
            at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:681)
            at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:103)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong. I spent few hours but couldn't find any solution.

Edit - I am using geneymotion emulator. The path I am using

file /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.gold.cameratwoapi/files/video.mp4

Thanks

Comment: EGL error 0x3003 is for "Bad alloc". Something wrong is happening in memory...

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what specific call is causing the above issues? Also, since you are presumabley saving your video, have you ensured that you have added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your application manifest file?

Comment: Thanks both, @Willis  I did write permission in the manifest file.I am using this path to store the file /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.gold.cameratwoapi/files/video.mp4. This problem happens at mMediaRecorder.stop();

Comment: Have you tried running the application on an actual device? I have had issues in the past when trying to save a file using the emulator, even though it is allowed.

Comment: @Willis, I don't have a device on API 21.

Comment: Well someone correct me if I'm wrong but the issue is probably associated with trying to make method calls linked to non-existent hardware. What I mean is I do not think you can reliable use hardware-based APIs, such as the `Camera2` or others, without actual hardware.

Comment: I use Nexus 7 (hardware) -  I have this error

Answer (score 30):

My solution is to change void stopRecordingVideo() as following:

```
private void stopRecordingVideo() {
// UI
mIsRecordingVideo = false;
mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.record);
// Added by Ben Ning, to resolve exception issue when stop recording.
try {
    mPreviewSession.stopRepeating();
    mPreviewSession.abortCaptures();
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

// Stop recording
mMediaRecorder.stop();
mMediaRecorder.reset();
```

}

Key is:

```
    try {
    mPreviewSession.stopRepeating();
    mPreviewSession.abortCaptures();
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It works on mine project, but can you explain more detail why have to stop preview twice before closing recorder?

Answer (score 6):

```
        private void stopRecordingVideo() {
// UI
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.record);
// Added by Ben Ning, to resolve exception issue when stop recording.
        try {
            mPreviewSession.stopRepeating();
            mPreviewSession.abortCaptures();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

// Stop recording
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Video saved: " + getVideoFile(activity),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        startPreview();
    }
```

this is working for me.

Answer (score 4):

After calling `mMediaRecorder.stop()` an `IllegalStateException` is always thrown. I've noticed that on devices with `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY` the `CameraDevice` changes status to error, immediately calling `onError()` in the `CameraDevice.StateCallback`.

In the sample you referenced, `onError()` closes the camera and finishes the activity, so just change `onError()` to re-open the camera, like this:

```
@Override
public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
    // mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    // cameraDevice.close();
    // mCameraDevice = null;
    // Activity activity = getActivity();
    // if (null != activity) {
    //  activity.finish();
    // }

    closeCamera();
    openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
}
```

It'd also be a good idea to put some check in there to make sure that if an error really did happen, that the commented out code gets called instead of entering a loop of trying to open the camera over and over.

Tested on a Moto G 2nd gen, with Android 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing with the CameraCaptureSession and the MediaRecorder but when you call `mMediaRecorder.stop()` I think it is destroying the surface used for the camera preview session which causes this error because the documentation says

> Once recording is stopped, you will have to configure it again as if it has just been constructed

Therefore if you call `PreviewSession.abortCaptures()` (`mPreviewSession.stopRepeating();` isn't necessary from what I gather) it stops the camera sending output to the recorder surface which will allow you to stop the MediaRecorder without issue.

`PreviewSession.abortCaptures();` doesn't instantly stop the camera preview output so you might find you need to call `MediaRecorder.stop()` in the `onClosed()` or `onReady()` method of the [CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `TimerTask` and a `Handler`. There is error direct to the mMediaRecorder.stop(). So I use this method

```
final Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        // Stop recording
        try {
            mPreviewSession.stopRepeating();
            mPreviewSession.abortCaptures();
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            mMediaRecorder.stop();
                            mMediaRecorder.reset();
                        }

                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(timerTask,30);
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            Log.e("----------------","---->>>>>>>>>"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```